# How to get the user email when he/she clicks on a website link in newsletter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to get the user email when he/she clicks on a link provided with the newsletter, I am using contact form 7 for sending the newsletter. So I am not able to pass the email in the query string so that whenever a user clicks on the email I can automatically get his/her email.

Can anyone help me with this that how can I do this?

Comment: What have you done to try this? Can you show your research and attempts?

Comment: Share your code of the form or what any code you are working with